# Intel VTune MPI Interfaces Performance Measurement

Tags: mpi, openmp, intel-vtune

I have a program written with openMP and MPI, I want to measure MPI interfaces specially. Profiling with vtune hotspots in the following commands:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREAD=6

cat >vtune.conf <<EOF
0-34     ./app
35       amplxe-cl -collect hotspots -no-follow-child  -trace-mpi -r result -- ./app
EOF

srun -N 6 -n 36 --multi-prog vtune.conf
```

In the result, the hotspots functions are MPI immediate functions like `opal_*, pthread*`, may I ask how to measure performance of those MPI interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the below corrections to your commands.

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=12

mpirun -n 16 –ppn 4 –l vtune -collect hotspots -k sampling-mode=hw -trace-mpi -result-dir <result directory path> -- ./app
```

If a MPI application is launched on multiple nodes, VTune Profiler creates a number of result directories per compute node in the current directory encapsulating the data for all the ranks running on the node in the same directory.

Please refer the below link to know the utilization of both the tools with MPI, Intel Advisor and Intel VTune profiler, to collect performance data at the node and core level

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/using-intel-advisor-and-vtune-amplifier-with-mpi.html